# Route request for Home.aspx to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

This has likely been answered (perhaps multiple times) but I can't quite seem to figure it out from any of the posts I'm finding.

Our old website had a Home.aspx and there are still links out there that point to this page. So in our MVC site I want a route that will take incoming requests for Home.aspx and route it to a controller.

From what I can tell MapPageRoute seems to do the opposite by mapping a route to a page. How do I route a request for a physical page to a controller though?

Comment: Would a simple redirect work for you? Easiest way I can think of would be to throw a dummy Home.aspx file in your app, with inline code which does a redirect in `Page_Load`

Comment: Perhaps it may... but just out of curiosity is this something that can't be done? I'm not an expert on SEO and it seems like often when I come to a logical solution such as this I find out that there is potential for it to screw our rankings so the more it works exactly like it does now the better.

Comment: But yes, ultimately I imagine we will end up 301ing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This should map the route however you want it to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SomeName",
    url: "Home.aspx",
    defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```